# How to configure unattended-upgrades to send mail, but not upgrade anything?

Tags: apt, unattended-upgrades

In the configs I see option

- To set up the informative mail about this (`Unattended-Upgrade::Mail` in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50-unattended-upgrades`)
- I can also turn the automatic package update on or off, in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrade`.

However, what I want:

1. If there is something to upgrade, I want to get the warning mails for that.
2. However, I don't want the software to upgrade anything. Only I want to upgrade anything, with my own hands.

Could this somehow be set up?

Comment: Have you tried `PT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";` together with `APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";`?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro My impression is that it would turn the whole mechanism off, and not only the actual package updates, but the docs aren't very clear, more exactly [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22APT%3A%3APeriodic%3A%3AUnattended-Upgrade%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) the results are essentially nothing.

Comment: You can always mail yourself the result of `apt-get update ; apt-get -s -o Debug::NoLocking=true upgrade | grep ^Inst` and not install an extra package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don’t need `unattended-upgrades` for this, `apt` can take care of updates and downloads by itself. See `/usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily` for details (this is called either by a cron job, or by a systemd timer); you can configure the following, in a file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`, *e.g.* `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic`:

- `APT::Periodic::Enable "1";` to enable the script;
- `APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";` to run `apt-get update` every day (0 disables, *n* > 1 runs it every *n* days);
- `APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "1";` to run `apt-get upgrade --download-only` every day (as above);
- `APT::Periodic::Verbose "1";` sends a progress report to root.

[`cron-apt`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/cron-apt) is another tool which can do this, along with emails with command outputs; however for basic scenarios such as the above it doesn’t add anything to the features now available in `apt`.

Both of these send emails with any output, not just when there are packages to upgrade. To get that behaviour, you could disable those emails (except on error), and supplement them with a cron job running `apt --list upgradable`.

[`apticron`](https://tracker.debian.org/apticron) is yet another tool which does this, but more closely fits your requirements: it sends email only when it determines that upgrades are available. It can also be configured to list only new upgrades (since the previous email), and it will use `apt-listchanges` to include the changelogs.

Comment: Finally apticron won. Tyvm!